# POVM advantage in state discrimination

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

Suppose we are given the task of discriminating, with minimum error, between a set of states $\{|\psi_1\rangle,|\psi_2\rangle,\ldots,|\psi_N\rangle\}$. In other words, we are given an unknown state form this set and our task is to output which of the states we were given.

Let $P_{err}$ be the probability of incorrectly identifying the state. Under what circumstances is this probability minimized by using a projective measurement?

Comment: This is either enough like a homework question that you should [read the homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/715/8563), or too broad to be answered in this format. What exactly is your question?

Comment: I'm willing to bet there is a nice succinct answer to this question.  Someone who works in quantum state discrimination could easily answer it while it might take you or I many hours of literature searching to find it.  Seems like the perfect kind of question to ask in my opinion.

Comment: Maybe you should quantify "advantage".  To discriminate $\left|0\right>$ from $\left|+\right>$ there is a POVM that will tell either "surely $\left|0\right>$", "surely $\left|+\right>$", or "I don't know".  This cannot be done with projective measurement.  The "surely $\left|0\right>$" POVM element is proportional to $\left|-\right>\left<-\right|$ and you can probably piece together the rest from there.

Comment: By advantage I mean that the error probability is decreased. I realize now that I should not have included the unambiguous case. I will edit the question accordingly. However, I must agree with Chris that this is the type of questions that may find a concise answer from an expert.

Comment: Well a trivial answer could be " if the states are orthogonal " :)